# QT C++ Framework QlistwidgetItem CONVERSION

Tags: c++, qt

I have a list you can fill it on your own with `QfileDialog` and put the selected files in a widgetList.

I can access the list and colour all those items and do whatever I want to, except this one problem:

I would like to select one item from the list and convert it somehow to `QStringList` so I can use it as a Phonon MediaSource.

I don't know how I can extract this item, I want the text shown in `ListWidget` and put it in my `mediaObj` so I can play it.

Here is a little bit of my code:

How i open the FileDialog (works):

```
 QStringList fileNames;
QFileDialog fDialog(this);
fDialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
fDialog.setNameFilter(tr("Music(*.mp3)"));
fDialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);

while (true) {
    if (fDialog.exec()) {
        fileNames = fDialog.selectedFiles();
        widget.list->addItems(fileNames);
        musicObj->enqueue(fileNames.last());
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

How I access one item clicked in the list:

```
 QListWidgetItem *list_itm = widget.list->currentItem();
 list_itm->setTextColor(Qt::red);
```

But I can extract the string shown on my cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

```
QListWidgetItem *list_itm = widget.list->currentItem();
list_itm->setTextColor(Qt::red);

QStringList list;
list << list_itm.text();
```

Unless I've misunderstood, you just want a `QStringList` with a single item in, the current widget item.

Comment: Haha, thanks you helped me to understand c++ more even if it wasn the stuff i was looking for. xD Thanks i just needed: musicObj->setCurrentSource(list_imt->text());